# Why i remove some item from the adapter viewPager2, viewPager can not call registerOnPageChangeCallback?

Tags: java, android

I added viewpager2 in my screen and set adapter on it, see adapter structure in below

```java
public class NewTravelListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewTravelListAdapter.VH> {

    MainActivityCallback newTravelCallback;
    public Picasso picasso;
    private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
    public ArrayList<NewTravelRequestPopUpModel> newTravelRequestPopUpModel;
    public OptionsAdapter optionsAdapter;
    private NewTravelSuggestPopupViewInterface.GetSize getSize;
    Context context;
    int viewHeight = 0;
    private CountDownCustumTimer circle_progress_bar_timer;
    ChangeItemTravelListInterface changeItemTravelListInterface;


    VH holder;

    public DiffUtil.ItemCallback<NewTravelRequestPopUpModel> diffUtil = new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<NewTravelRequestPopUpModel>(){
        @Override
        public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull NewTravelRequestPopUpModel oldItem, @NonNull NewTravelRequestPopUpModel newItem) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override

        public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull NewTravelRequestPopUpModel oldItem, @NonNull NewTravelRequestPopUpModel newItem) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    public AsyncListDiffer<NewTravelRequestPopUpModel> differ = new AsyncListDiffer<NewTravelRequestPopUpModel>(this , diffUtil);


    public NewTravelListAdapter(@NonNull MainActivityCallback newTravelCallback, Picasso picasso,
                                ArrayList<NewTravelRequestPopUpModel> newTravelRequestPopUpModel,
                                NewTravelSuggestPopupViewInterface.GetSize getSize ,
                                ChangeItemTravelListInterface changeItemTravelListInterface){

        this.newTravelCallback = newTravelCallback;
        this.picasso = picasso;
        this.getSize=getSize;
        this.newTravelRequestPopUpModel = newTravelRequestPopUpModel;
        optionsAdapter = new OptionsAdapter(picasso, newTravelRequestPopUpModel.get(0).optionsModelArrayList);
        this.changeItemTravelListInterface = changeItemTravelListInterface;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public VH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        ItemNewTravelSuggestPopupLayoutBinding binding = ItemNewTravelSuggestPopupLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater , parent , false);
        return new VH(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull VH holder, int position) {
        NewTravelRequestPopUpModel item = differ.getCurrentList().get(position);
        this.holder = holder;
        View view = holder.binding.newTravelSuggestPopup;
        view.post(() -> {
            viewHeight = view.getHeight()+20;
            getSize.getHeight((view.getHeight()+50));
        });
        

}
            

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return differ.getCurrentList().size();
    }




    public void setList(ArrayList<NewTravelRequestPopUpModel> newTravelRequestPopUpModel){
        differ.submitList(newTravelRequestPopUpModel);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    public void removeItem(int pos){

        notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        changeItemTravelListInterface.itemRemoved(pos);
    }

    public static class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ItemNewTravelSuggestPopupLayoutBinding binding;
        public VH(ItemNewTravelSuggestPopupLayoutBinding binding ) {
            super(binding.newTravelSuggestPopup);
            this.binding= binding;
        }
    }

}
```

Then I set adapter above to the viewPAger2 and listen with `registerOnPageChangeCallback` to viewPager2 scroll.

```java
 adapterList = new NewTravelListAdapter(newTravelCallback , picasso  , newTravelRequestPopUpModel,
                getSize , this);
        setList(newTravelRequestPopUpModel);



        binding.viewPager.setAdapter(adapterList);


        binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                super.onPageSelected(position);
                selectedTravel = newTravelRequestPopUpModel.get(position);
                ChangeItem(selectedTravel , position);

                newTravelCallback.changeRequest(selectedTravel , height);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);

            }
        });
```

Now my problem is that after calling the ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍`removeItem‍‍‍` method in the `NewTravelListAdapter` adapter
Removed the item from the adapter, but I can't listen to the adapter change

Comment: Missing a DataObserver??

Comment: No, I did test it, just conflict in timers. What do you think?

Comment: Actually the problem is, ur issue is not so clear. Can u please explain as: 1) what u want to do? 2) what u tried

Comment: No, I haven't lost my DataObserver @DiLDoST